# How to customise order state after generating invoice in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice

When I am generating an invoice in Magento then the order status becomes processing. means it uses state processing

I want to change it to pending payment or new order state there.

Is any way to customize order state after generating invoice if then tell me where to do it?

Comment: please help me anyone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion  create ***a status[name:pending payment ]*** of  ***state processing*** then ***assign*** that  ***custom status as default status*** of state : `processing`

You can do all thing from ***admin>System>Order Statuses***

I Guss that you does not need any coding .

Comment: but i want to change via code for inoice only so please help me

Comment: and i want to change state for generating invoice questionedited

Comment: hello please help me any  one..

Comment: little  bust now.. get back to you shortly

Comment: i am waiting for your positive reply

Comment: hello help me to customise reply anyone..

Comment: hello please help me with this customisation

Comment: any one help me to change state when invoice is creating

Comment: Iif order state is become processing then it become create issue  whenever....try it chnage it state ot new nad payment review

Comment: i want to change it to new or payment review state when creating invoice help me where i set new or payment review state for creating invoice.

Comment: hello amit help me...